# Ruby on Rails create CSV with separate lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a csv file for the user to download.  I am able to create the file ok, but am having problems adding a new line for each separate entry.  I read some old responses that recommended adding csv << "\n", but that does not seem to work properly.  Excel is able to open the CSV file correctly, but I need to be able to view it in notepad.  In notepad, it is just one long string of words.

The code that I am using is:

```
csv_file = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << attributes
  @volunteers.each do |v|
    csv << [v.id, v.last_name, v.first_name]
  end
end

send_data csv_file, filename: "volunteers.csv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separators are by default new line `\n` but if you're opening it in Notepad on Windows the separators need to be carriage-feed and new-line `\r\n`

So do it this way...

```
csv_file = CSV.generate(headers: true, row_sep: "\r\n" ) do |csv|
```